# I am facing ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'testCases' while running a code in google collab what to do

Tags: python, python-3.x

Running a code in google collab showing me NoModuleFound what to do?

Answer (score 0):

Do `!pip install <module-name>` if it is a package. Else, add the code for the user defined module in a cell before the one that calls it :)